# wants to insert record in oracle

Tags: c#, oracle

```
if (tbsitename.Text != null)
        { 
            tbsitecode.Text = dm.GetData("select nvl(max(to_number(id)),0)+1 from setups_setup").ToString();
            //string code = dm.GetData("select lpad(nvl(max(to_number(code)),0)+1,2,0) from setups_setup where type = 'ISITE'").ToString();

            MessageBox.Show(dm.GetData("select max(id) from setups_setup").ToString());

            //int suc = dm.SetData("Insert into setups_setup(id) values (id)");

            //if (suc > 0)
            //{
            //    tbsitecode.Text = dm.GetData("select max(code) from setups_setup where type = 'ISITE'").ToString();

            //    MessageBox.Show("Record Saved.....");
            //}
        }
```

Dear ALL,
I am new in this group as well as in c#/asp.net.
I want to insert record in oracle, there is a primary key ID which I want to generate but the query isn't giving me new ID.
If I am running this query in oracle it is working fine.
any suggestion please...

Comment: I think its better to use sequence.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798766/how-to-create-an-oracle-sequence-starting-with-max-value-from-a-table

Answer (score 0):

1. I think sequence do it for you,
2. This is sample [how to insert with getting value from sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12949278/how-to-get-the-sequence-trigger-primary-key-that-is-inserted-into-the-database-a)
3. Remember - use parameters instead pure query (SQL Injection)